# React-native : Transfer large data between js and native (java android)

Tags: react-native

i have a question.

i know we can use readableArray and writeableArray to transfer array between js and native.
But i must copy data from true array buffer to it.

Have any other way to do this (faster?) like a memory use by all js and native? I wish transfer a lot of data between them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an excellent [Under the hood presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/player/bd531dcaf56e4c148bd414e6af2ef5b6#) of the react-native architecture by Martin Konicek. Seems that the two VM's (the JS one and the JVM) cannot share object references. I am working on a video application and I am planning to implement it natively in Java to avoid the conversion of the buffer back and forth.